# Suppose that $X$ is a sub affine variety of $Y$ , and let $φ : X \to Y$ be the inclusion. Prove that $φ^*$ is surjective...

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, field-theory, pullback

where $\varphi^*$ is the pullback homomorphism $k[Y] \to k[X]$

If you could also give an explanation for as to what the pullback morphism is, I'd really appreciate it; my understanding is somewhat shaky.

Comment: do you mean a closed sub-variety?

Comment: I suppose? It's not specified. In fact, we haven't even brought up the notion of closed vs not closed varieties, so I don't know what that would mean.

Comment: it matters... for instance, suppose $Y$ is the affine line. Then $k[Y] = k[t]$, polys in one variable. Say $X= Y - \text{a point}$, which is an open (in the so-called Zariski topology) sub-variety of $Y$. Then $k[X] = k[t, 1/t]$, so $\phi^*\colon k[Y] \to k[X]$, which is the inclusion map here, is not surjective.

Comment: $k[Y]$ is the set of regular functions $f: Y \to k$.  The pullback map is simply precomposition: composing $f$ with $\varphi$ yields a regular map $f \circ \varphi : X \to k$, which is an element of $k[X]$.

Comment: @peterag: This class is independent of topology. I suppose we should assume whatever is necessary for the statement to be true, but we should keep in mind that this is an algebraic geometry class that only assumes two semesters of modern algebra.

Comment: @m.lekk peterag is just saying that you need to include your definition of variety in your question.  It seems very likely to me that you're only considering affine varieties, which are given as the vanishing locus in affine space of a set of polynomials.  (And maybe you only consider irreducible varieties...)

Comment: @Quasicoherent you were faster than I - but of course both the $X$ and $Y$ of my example are affine - so what are the definitions...

Comment: @peterag Your $X$ is not an affine variety in the more elementary sense: it is not given as the vanishing locus of a set of polynomials.  It's quasi-affine (an open subset of an affine variety), and yes, it is isomorphic to a hyperbola which is an affine variety.

Comment: @Quasicoherent how unkind of you to forestall me from making the hyperbola isomorphism objection... fwiw https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_variety also calls my $X$ affine. But of course, we all agree on what the OP must want/need - but it would still have been nice to have the OP's working definitions stated. ciao!

Answer (score 1):

$k[X]$ is just the set of polynomial functions on $X$. I am assuming you are using affine varieties. So an element of $k[X]$ is represented by a polynomial function $p(x)$. The map $\varphi^*:k[Y]\to k[X]$ is defined by 
$$\varphi^*(p)(x)=p(\varphi(x))$$ So basically what it is saying is that any polynomial function on $X$ comes from some polynomial function on $Y$. This is obvious since polynomials are globally defined.

Another point of view is that $k[X]=k[x_1,\ldots ,x_n]/I(X)$ and you have $I(Y)\subseteq I(X)$, now the pullback is

$$k[x_1,\ldots ,x_n]/I(Y)\to k[x_1,\ldots ,x_n]/I(X)$$ and this is clearly surjective.

Comment: I'm a bit unhappy about the word 'affine' - e.g., 'my' example above. Comments? Although I'm sure your answer is basically what the O.P. wants...

Comment: @peterag Yeah, I dont think this is what he means by the question, if this were an issue, he would specify his definitions. I just take subvariety to mean closed.

Comment: No, I meant affine varities; I forgot to specify that.

Comment: Yes, I assumed so from the notation.

Comment: For the second version of the proof, can you explain why $$k[x_1,\ldots ,x_n]/I(X)\to k[x_1,\ldots ,x_n]/I(Y)$$ is surjective?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote them reversed, I have edited now to make more sense. The second proof is the same as the first, the map is basically, $p(x)+I(Y)\mapsto p(x)+I(X)$.

Comment: I'm still not seeing how the pullback is "clearly subjective;" could you elaborate?

Comment: Given $p(x)+I(X)$ it is in the image since $p(x)+I(Y)$ maps to it.

Comment: That's the definition of surjective. But how do we know that for all p(x) + I(X) there's some p(x) + I(Y) that maps to it?

Comment: Yeah its the EXACT SAME $p(x)$ !.